# Cannot find def of .has_func or .get_func

Tags: rust, huggingface

I was reading through the code for HuggingFace's candle crate and found two methods whose definitions I couldn't find. The first is [.has_func](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/8c991df3945a7c86ae86a7a52a74639ec321cef2/candle-core/src/cuda_backend.rs#L190) and the second is [.get_func](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/8c991df3945a7c86ae86a7a52a74639ec321cef2/candle-core/src/cuda_backend.rs#L201).

How can I find the definitions of these methods?

Here's what I have tried:

- Searching for the string "has_func" in the repo
- Googling "rust has_func" and checking if any of the results are relevant.
- Checking if hovering in Github can point me to the def

It raised a more general question in my mind, I wanted to enumerate all the places a method could come from for a struct defined in a given crate, here's what I can think of:

- The method is defined somewhere in that crate (possibly obscured if defined in a macro)
- It could be the default definition of a method in a trait that the struct has and the trait is defined in some dependency.
- Something else? Maybe FFI related?

Comment: They might have been generated with a macro. If this is the case, then using rust-analyzer's "jump to definition" will jump to the macro invocation.

Comment: The definition appears to be here: https://github.com/coreylowman/cudarc/blob/main/src/driver/safe/launch.rs but it's not clear to me how that's possible because the "self" appears to be the outer struct CudaDevice and not the inner cudarc::driver::CudaDevice

Comment: Maybe they are the same and there is `pub use` somewhere?

Comment: That's because [it impls `Deref`](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/8c991df3945a7c86ae86a7a52a74639ec321cef2/candle-core/src/cuda_backend.rs#L95-L100).

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. Not sure what the protocol is here, do you want to put that as an answer then I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find the definition of something is to put it in rust-analyzer. It can almost always do that.

In this case, it seems to come from [`cudarc::driver::safe::CudaDevice`](https://docs.rs/cudarc/latest/cudarc/driver/safe/struct.CudaDevice.html#method.has_func), which [the type `Deref`s to](https://github.com/huggingface/candle/blob/8c991df3945a7c86ae86a7a52a74639ec321cef2/candle-core/src/cuda_backend.rs#L95-L100).